# How to serialize, convert or access a Row Type Variable in SAP HANA

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

[When creating a row-wise trigger](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/20d5a65575191014946db96aaedbef5b.html) in SAP HANA, a reference to a [Row type variable](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.04/en-US/869b4b1c5c7847cba246eb8e210d72bb.html) can be obtained. E.g. in the example below `:new_row` and `:old_row` are row type variables.

```sql
create trigger test_trigger
    after insert on test_table
    referencing new row new_row, old row old_row
    for each row
begin
```

I am attempting to serialize or convert the Row type variable values to a string or binary type of object. I have not been able to find a way of doing this directly. I.e.

```sql
INSERT INTO result_table(row_data) VALUES (<somehow serialize :new_row>);
```

As an alternative, I could iterate over the column values in the row (`:new_row`) and convert each of them into a string/binary value in turn, but I couldn't find a way of doing this either.

**Note**, this has to happen inside the trigger, and as such, [Dynamic SQL](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.04/en-US/966714d37630404983e8f4e3708ae79c.html) is not an option as it [is not support inside a trigger](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/20d5a65575191014946db96aaedbef5b.html) with SAP HANA.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: What is the purpose of storing all columns in a combined single column?

Comment: A single column isn't strictly speaking necessary. However, we would either want to keep the schema for the `result_table` the same, or update it automatically if the row's structure was changed.

Comment: What result table? If the gets changed, you could create a view that transforms the data accordingly to produce an unchanged result structure - that view however needs to be changed together with the Schema change.